# Write blocker, blocked operations

Tags: forensics

In forensics, write blockers devices should block every operation that might change the hard drive content.
**Besides the write operation what other operations should a write blocker block?**

Comment: @MatthewPeters, not a homework question, i'm new to forensics, that's all   (if you want my linkedin profile or something ...)

Answer (score 1):

The [concept of a write blocker](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Write_Blockers) is *to ensure the forensic integrity* of a system while simultaneously [forensically imaging](http://www.forensicon.com/resources/articles/what-is-forensic-hard-drive-imaging/) that system. This is accomplished by permitting *read-only* operations to a file system, thus a write blocker will prevent all *write* operations by intercepting them and either translating them into a *read* operation (if possible) or simply disallowing the write operation.

For instance, a hardware blocker may simply just not include the physical connections for writing (as with USB) and a software write blocker may intercept otherwise write operations -such as disallowing metadata to be changed when viewing an image.

[Taken from here:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forensic_disk_controller)

> The United States National Institute of Justice operates a Computer Forensics Tool Testing (CFTT) program which formally identifies the following top-level tool requirements:
>
> 1. A hardware write block (HWB) device shall not transmit a command to
>      a protected storage device that modifies the data on the storage
>      device.
> 2. An HWB device shall return the data requested by a read operation.
> 3. An HWB device shall return without modification any access-significant information requested from the drive.
> 4. Any error condition reported by the storage device to the HWB device shall be reported to the host.

Comment: Yes, the write operations are blocked, my question is besides the "write" operation what other operations might alter the integrity of the hard drive and hence must be blocked

Comment: Apart from physical disruption (IE hitting the hard drive with a hammer), the only way to alter the integrity is to *write* in some way to the hard drive. To clarify, a *write* is essentially the "I" in the ["IO model"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output), thus anything can (and should) be blocked...

Answer (score 1):

Besides the write operations, there are other operations that might alter the content a hard drive. One of these operations is the "Secure Erase" command: 
https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase

Comment: The secure erase command is still (in my opinion) a write operation, just to a different portion of the system -the SDD controller. In any case a proper write blocker (hardware or software) should be able to detect this operation and cancel it.

Comment: A separate question that you might be interested in is "In what ways can a write blocker be circumvented [by the examiner/examinee]?" or perhaps you are just interested in malware or hacks then "What hacks or malware exist that prevent writeblockers from working properly?" For instance, with your secure erase example there is [this](https://belkasoft.com/en/why-ssd-destroy-court-evidence) which is essentially a failsafe for an SSD.